# Method sort(Map<Integer,Object>) is not applicable for the arguments (Map<Integer,Entity>)

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a static method with the header of:

```
public static Map<Integer, Object> sort(Map<Integer, Object> inputMap) {
```

and I try to call it using:

```
MapUtil.sort(entities);
```

This is when entities is set to:

```
private Map<Integer, Entity> entities = new HashMap<Integer, Entity>();
```

I am getting this error:

> The method sort(Map) in the type MapUtil is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Map)

Entity extends Object, so shouldn't I be able to throw a Map to a method that needs Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that `Entity` extends `Object`, but `Map<Integer, Entity>` does NOT extend `Map<Integer, Object>` due to the way generics works. If this was allowed, you could add an object to the map which maps to entities.

Here's a reference from Oracle's Java Tutorials:

[image]

By making the sort method generic:

```
public static Map<Integer, Object> sort(Map<Integer, Object> inputMap) {
```

By changing it to this:

```
public static <T> Map<Integer, T> sort(Map<Integer, T> inputMap) {
```

Then the compiler will allow any class to be used in place of `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public static Map<Integer, Object> sort(Map<Integer, Object> inputMap)
```

to

```
public static <T> Map<Integer, T> sort(Map<Integer, T> inputMap)
```